# Best way to track users though a website

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to track my users through a website. I've installed google analytics but its a bit too anonymous for me. I'd like to track users on a per user/per visit basis.

Is there a service out there that does this (I can't seem to find one)? Would I be better off writing some bespoke code to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.kissmetrics.com/